# error while importing keras ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'; 'tensorflow' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i tried import keras but it says:

> > > import keras
> > >           Using TensorFlow backend.
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >             File 
> > >           "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
> > >          packages/keras/**init**.py", line 3, in  
> > >               from . import utils
> > >             File 
> > >           "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
> > >           packages/keras/utils/**init**.py", line 6, in 
> > >               from . import conv_utils
> > >             File 
> > >           "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
> > >          packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
> > >               from .. import backend as K
> > >             File 
> > >           "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
> > >          packages/keras/backend/**init**.py", line 89, in  
> > >               from .tensorflow_backend import *
> > >             File 
> > >           "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
> > >          packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
> > >               import tensorflow as tf
> > >             File "/Users/elanchezhian/tensorflow.py", line 2, in 
> > >               from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
> > >           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'; 'tensorflow' is not a package

i am using mac os high sierra and i am running keras in python3 and i installed keras with pip

edit: ok ,i already had a file named tensorflow.py ,i removed it and new error came

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/**init**.py", line 3, in 
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py", line 6, in 
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/**init**.py", line 89, in 
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: bad magic number in 'tensorflow': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

edit: i have removed tensorflow.pyc now this error came :

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version 
of 
numpy is 0xb
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2018-10-21 10:53:26.723451: F 
tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] 
Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr 
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: try to install tensorflow ```pip install tensorflow``` if you didn't already, because keras use it as backend

Comment: i already did, but i did it once to check ,but ,it still didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is named `tensorflow.py`, which conflicts with the name of the real tensorflow package. Name your script something else.

Comment: ok ,i already had a file named tensorflow.py ,i removed it and new error came see it in the edit of the post

Comment: If there is a `tensorflow.pyc` or `tensorflow.pyo` file in your directory, remove those too.

Comment: hmmm ok there was a file called tensorflow.pyc i removed it and now another error came see it in the post  i edited

Comment: hmmm sorry ,i did it wrong thats why, i will edit the question and tell you

Answer (score 0):

How about generate new virtualenv than 'tensorflow'?
I recommend to generate new virtualenv named 'venv' for example.
In my Anaconda environment, I have same problem but after generating new one, it solved.

when generate 'tensorflow' virtualenv, I had same moduleerror like you.

```
$ conda create -n venv pip python=3.6
$ source activate venv
(venv)$
```

But after generating new virtualenv, it works successfully. 
I hope your code will work successfully too.